# How to write SQL query to get the 2nd heaviest animal from each zoo?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Here are the two tables(animal_weight and zoo_directory):

[image: animal_weights]
[image: zoo_directory]

I am confused on how to retrieve the 2nd heaviest animal from each zoo. I was thinking using the MAX function or a subquery but I am not entirely sure. Here is the query I got so far:

```
SELECT
zoo_directory.zoo_ID AS 'zoo_ID',
zoo_name,
weight_lbs
FROM animal_weights 
INNER JOIN zoo_directory
ON animal_weights.zoo_ID = zoo_directory.zoo_ID
ORDER BY zoo_name ASC;
```

which returns this:

[image: sqlquery]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dense_rank` window function to give a rank with weight and per zoo and then filter it out the second highest.

```
select zoo_id,zoo_name,weight_lbs
from
(
select z.zoo_id as 'zoo_ID'
      ,zoo_name
      ,weight_lbs
      ,dense_rank() over (partition by  z.zoo_id order by weight_lbs desc) rnk
  from animal_weights a
  inner join zoo_directory z
  on a.zoo_id = z.zoo_id
)
where rnk = 2;
```

Comment: Sweet thanks! Would I have to add an alias to the subquery?

Comment: @Aidan Mendonca, Some databases like `MySQL` and `SQL Server` will give syntax error where as in `Oracle` or `SQLite` it is not necessary to give an alias to subquery. But I would agree together with you that we can give an `alias` name always.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    b.zoo_ID AS 'Zoo_ID',
    b.zoo_name AS 'Name',
    MAX(a.weight_lbs) AS 'Weight'
FROM
    animal_weight a
        INNER JOIN
    zoo_directory b ON a.zoo_ID = b.zoo_ID
WHERE
    a.weight_lbs NOT IN (SELECT 
            MAX(a.weight_lbs)
        FROM
            animal_weight a
                INNER JOIN
            zoo_directory b ON a.zoo_ID = b.zoo_ID
        GROUP BY b.zoo_name)
GROUP BY b.zoo_name;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked as well. I was using it in a MSSQL virtual env and was giving me an error but when I ran it in SQLITE it worked!